# Check if two variables have values from two different sets, the DRY way

Tags: python, coding-style, dry

I have a range of values (`L,R,U,D`) and two variables, `d` and `newd`, containing one of them. I need to check if `d` and `newd` are in the same subset (`L,R` or `U,D`) or not.
I know I can do this:

```py
d in {'L','R'} and newd in {'U','D'} or d in {'U','D'} and newd in {'L','R'}
```

this indeed returns `False` if they both have values in `L,R` or `U,D`, and `True` otherwise. Still, I find it much reduntant. Some suggestions about a more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that there are only two sets and that your values *must* be in one or the other, then you can simplify it to this:

```
(d in set1) == (newd in set2)
```

Explanation:

- If d is in set 1 and newd is in set 2, both sides of the `==` are `True`, so the expression returns `True`.
- If d is in set 2 and newd is in set 1, both sides of the `==` are `False`, so the expression returns `True`.
- If they are in the same set, one side of the `==` will return `False` and the other `True` so the result of the expression will be `False`.

Comment: Not bad at all... I wonder if there is a way to do this mentioning only one set, but maybe that's not possible.

Comment: I meant one set just one time

Comment: @etuardu: `len({d, newd} - set1) == 1`

Comment: great, I was hoping for something like that! Only, this would return `True` when d==newd if both are in set2, but it's easy to fix (and in my real scenery was even painless). Nice and smart. I already up-voted and accepted your answer but you may add this other alternative if you please.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
In [8]: dmap = {'L':0, 'R':0, 'U':1, 'D':1}

In [9]: dmap[d] != dmap[newd]
Out[9]: False
```